# powershell Get-ChildItem result in array

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, member-enumeration

`(Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse  -Path $path).Fullname`  returns array of full names
`(Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse  -Path $path).Name`  returns array of files names
but
`(Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse  -Path $path).Length` returns only one value - the count of elements

Question - how to get result as array of file lengths ?

Answer (score 7):

To complement [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67547058/45375):

**tl;dr**

Use of the [`.ForEach()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach) enables a concise and performant solution:

```sh
# Return the files' .Length property values as a collection.
(Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path $path).ForEach('Length')
```

---

As pointed out in Mathias' answer, **type-native properties** - such as `.Length` on array instances - **take precedence** over the so-called **[member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375)** that you tried to perform - that is, you wanted to collect the `.Length` property values of the *elements* of your collection (array; the [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instances output by [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)), and return them as an (`[object[]]`) *array*.

- [GitHub issue #7445](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7445) discusses this situational ambiguity and proposes introducing a *dedicated operator*, say `%.` so that you can unambiguously request *either* regular property access *or* member-access enumeration.

A perhaps surprising aspect of member-access enumeration is that it applies *pipeline logic* in that it ***situationally returns a scalar*, namely if the collection happens to contain just *one* element**.

- E.g., `@(Get-Date).Year.GetType().Name` returns an `System.Int32`, not `Object[]`, indicating that an integer rather than a (single-element) *array* containing an integer was returned.
- [GitHub issue #6802](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6802) discusses this.

**Member-access enumeration is not only convenient, but also *fast***, because it avoids looping / enumeration *in PowerShell code*.

**Use of the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) or [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) *cmdlets***, as shown in Mathias' answer, is definitely **a *functional* but *slow* workaround** for not being able to use member-access enumeration in a given situation, due to use of the *pipeline*, which isn't necessary for input that that is *already in memory in full*.

Therefore, **use of the [`.ForEach()` array *method*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach)** - using the overload where you simply specify the target property *name* (`'Length'`) - is a **concise and better-performing alternative**.

- Note: Unlike with member-access enumeration, the **return value from `.ForEach()` is *always* a *collection***, albeit not an *array*: it is of type `[System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[psobject]]`, which, however, will behave like an array in most contexts.<sup>[1]</sup>

---

<sup>[1] Unlike an array, this type of collection is *extensible* (you can add or remove elements). Due to the element type being `[psobject]`, each element is *typically invisibly* wrapped in this type; e.g., `42 -is [psobject]` is `$false`, but `@(42).ForEach({ $_ })[0] -is [psobject]` is `$true`. Unfortunately, there *are* cases where this near-invisible wrapper results in different behavior - see [GitHub issue #5579](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5579).</sup>

Answer (score 5):

The one value you get is indeed the length of the resulting array - the Array class has an explicit [`Length` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.length) that takes precedence over property enumeration.

To get the individual `Length` property values from each item in the array, pipe to either `Select-Object` or `ForEach-Object`, like so:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path $path |ForEach-Object -MemberName Length
# or 
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path $path |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Length
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example you get the `Length` of the resulting array.

`Get-ChildItem -File` returns an array of `System.IO.FileInfo`. So you need to take (select) the `Length` attribute of every entry in the array. This is done by using `Select-Object` or just `select`:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse  -Path $path | Select-Object Length
```

which would give you an array of objects containing the file's length as `Length` property. You can also select multiple properties:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse  -Path $path | Select-Object Name, Length
```