# Powershell - How to retrieve Object[] data

Tags: arrays, powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-5.1, member-enumeration

I'm trying to get some data from api request, but ***rank*** it's getting corrupted.
I have this code in a file:

```
$queryResult=Invoke-restmethod -Uri "https://aoe2.net/api/leaderboard?game=aoe2de&leaderboard_id=3&steam_id=76561198011209758"

Write-Output "COMPLETE RETURN"
$queryResult

Write-Output "LEADERBOARD"
$queryResult.leaderboard

Write-Output "INDIVIDUAL ITEMS"
Write-Output $("profile_id: "+$queryResult.leaderboard.profile_id)
Write-Output $("rank: "+$queryResult.leaderboard.rank)
Write-Output $("rating: "+$queryResult.leaderboard.rating)
Write-Output $("steam_id: "+$queryResult.leaderboard.steam_id)
Write-Output $("icon: "+$queryResult.leaderboard.icon)
Write-Output $("name: "+$queryResult.leaderboard.name)
Write-Output $("clan: "+$queryResult.leaderboard.clan)
Write-Output $("country: "+$queryResult.leaderboard.country)
Write-Output $("previous_rating: "+$queryResult.leaderboard.previous_rating)
Write-Output $("highest_rating: "+$queryResult.leaderboard.highest_rating)
Write-Output $("streak: "+$queryResult.leaderboard.streak)
Write-Output $("lowest_streak: "+$queryResult.leaderboard.lowest_streak)
Write-Output $("highest_streak: "+$queryResult.leaderboard.highest_streak)
Write-Output $("games: "+$queryResult.leaderboard.games)
Write-Output $("wins: "+$queryResult.leaderboard.wins)
Write-Output $("losses: "+$queryResult.leaderboard.losses)
Write-Output $("drops: "+$queryResult.leaderboard.drops)
Write-Output $("last_match: "+$queryResult.leaderboard.last_match)
Write-Output $("last_match_time: "+$queryResult.leaderboard.last_match_time)
```

Whenever i ran it, it shows:

```
COMPLETE RETURN


total          : 50403
leaderboard_id : 3
start          : 1
count          : 1
leaderboard    : {@{profile_id=518981; rank=4690; rating=1414; steam_id=76561198011209758; icon=; name=[LdS]Nestoter; clan=LDS14; country=UY; previous_rating=1398; highest_rating=1432; streak=1; lowest_streak=-10; highest_streak=8;
                 games=141; wins=80; losses=61; drops=1; last_match=1619919442; last_match_time=1619919442}}

LEADERBOARD
profile_id      : 518981
rank            : 4690
rating          : 1414
steam_id        : 76561198011209758
icon            :
name            : [LdS]Nestoter
clan            : LDS14
country         : UY
previous_rating : 1398
highest_rating  : 1432
streak          : 1
lowest_streak   : -10
highest_streak  : 8
games           : 141
wins            : 80
losses          : 61
drops           : 1
last_match      : 1619919442
last_match_time : 1619919442

INDIVIDUAL ITEMS
profile_id: 518981
rank: 1
rating: 1414
steam_id: 76561198011209758
icon:
name: [LdS]Nestoter
clan: LDS14
country: UY
previous_rating: 1398
highest_rating: 1432
streak: 1
lowest_streak: -10
highest_streak: 8
games: 141
wins: 80
losses: 61
drops: 1
last_match: 1619919442
last_match_time: 1619919442
```

I don't understand why ***rank*** changes from 4690 to 1, when I print the variable **$queryResult** and **$queryResult.leaderboard** contents it clearly shows that rank=4690, but when i access the innermost element it prints rank: 1.

Why ***rank*** changes from 4690 to 1?

You can copy the code and try yourself, the API is public.

Thanks

Comment: Your invoke-restmethod returns an array of PSObjects. $queryResult.leaderboard[0].ranks will give you the correct value.

Comment: Please, share you json source. Long shot: the `Rank` property is an array with a single item `"Rank"=[4690]`. Meaning that you probably need to do this: `$queryResult.leaderboard[0].rank`.

Comment: @iRon is right; read [Array.Rank Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.rank?view=net-5.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron) has provided the crucial pointer: **Because `$queryResult.leaderboard` is an *array*, which *itself* has a [`.Rank`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Array.Rank) property, you must explicitly access the element(s) of interest to get *their* `.rank` property value** (note that property access is case-*insensitive* in PowerShell, as PowerShell generally is):

```sh
# Note the [0] for access to the 1st element.
$queryResult.leaderboard[0].rank # -> 4690
```

<sup>You can determine that `$queryResult.leaderboard` is an array with `$queryResult.leaderboard | Get-Member` or `$queryResult.leaderboard.GetType().Name`, or you can *infer* it from the for-display representation: the *outer* `{...}` in `{@{profile_id=518981; ..}}` indicates that the value is a *collection* (though not necessarily an *array*).</sup>

**The reason this explicit element access (`[0]`) *isn't* necessary for your *other* properties is due to a feature called [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375)**:

- It conveniently allows you to use property access on a *collection* in order to have the property values of its *elements* returned:

  - With a *multi*-element collection, the elements' property values are returned as an *array* (`[object[]]`), but - as in the pipeline - with a *single-element* collection, the only element's property value is returned as-is.
  - Therefore, for instance, given an object `$obj = [pscustomobject] @{ profile_id = 518981 }`:

    - *Single-element* case: `@($obj).profile_id` is effectively the same as:
      `@($obj)[0].profile_id` / `$obj.profile_id`
    - *Multi-element* case: `@($obj, $obj).profile_id` is effectively the same as:
      `$obj | ForEach-Object { $_.profile_id }`
- However, **if the collection *itself* has a property by the given name, that *collection-level property takes precedence*** - which is what happened with `.Rank`.

  - [GitHub issue #7445](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7445) discusses this situational ambiguity and proposes introducing a *dedicated operator*, say `%.` so that you can unambiguously request *either* regular property access *or* member-access enumeration.
  - As a **general workaround** that is faster than the use of [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) or [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object), you can use `.ForEach('rank')`, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67547356/45375).